# Learn new (related) technologies or get certified?

Tags: software-industry, career-development

I am currently working as Java Developer, still young (22 yrs old), having a very good set of Java/Java EE technical skills.

To continuously develop and enhance my technical skills,
what would be the **first** thing to do (or to focus) and its advantages and disadvantages:

- Get (at least) level 2 certification (java/java ee), or
- Develop and enchance all my java/java ee technical skills and learn new (related) technologies.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is believed that software engineer's would do great if they develop a T shape knowledge base.

1. Depth of the vertical bar in one skill set.
2. Breadth of the horizontal bar in developing skills in a wide range of technologies.

If your focus is to develop your technical skills, you should pick a direction to go to. The goal could be a particular position you are interested to be in or expertise you think you like to have. In short I would do the following if I were you.

> while(Learning == True){
>
> 1. Pick a goal say expert in X or a position X which interest you.
> 2. Think of what skill set being X would require
> 3. Chart a plan towards this goal
> 4. Develop the skill
> 5. Self analysis of the skill and review of the list of things you want to be. }

Good luck for a bright future.